# Custom Stringstream - Convert std::wstring & std::string

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, visual-c++, c++03

I've got a template class derived from `std::basic_stringstream<typename TString::value_type...>`, as you can see. The problem happens while trying to convert them. It's probably an obvious problem, though I cannot seem to figure out the solution.

As example in `main`, I have a simple `std::wstring` and initialize it with `L"123"`.
After the `std::wstring` has been constructed, the operator of the custom `basic_stringstream` class is called (depending on `std::wstring` or `std::string`).

Inspecting the `WCStringStream` object for debugging purposes, shows that it contains - instead of the string `L"123"`, the address of the first element of the entered string. The functions `to_bytes` and `from_bytes` do return the correct converted string, so the only problem left is the operator being called in both operator-functions:

```
*this << std::wstring_convert<...>().xx_bytes(s);
```

***Example:***
Template class is `std::wstring`.
Input is a `std::string`.
`&operator<<(const std::string &s)` is being called.
String is converted.
`&operator<<(const std::wstring &s)` is being called.
String-type matches with template type.
Operator of base-class (`basic_stringstream`) is called. (Or `std::operator...`)

***Result:***
Inspecting: `{_Stringbuffer={_Seekhigh=0x007f6808 L"003BF76C췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍...}...}`
`WCStringStream<std::wstring>::str()` **->** `"003BF76C"`

***Expected result:***
`"123"`

What's going wrong here ?

---

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define NOMINMAX
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <codecvt>

template<class TString>
class WCStringStream : public std::basic_stringstream<typename TString::value_type,
    std::char_traits<typename TString::value_type>,
    std::allocator<typename TString::value_type> >
{
    typedef typename TString::value_type CharTraits;
    typedef std::basic_stringstream<CharTraits, std::char_traits<CharTraits>, std::allocator<CharTraits> > MyStream;
    //more typedefs...

public:
    //Constructor...
    inline WCStringStream(void) { }
    inline WCStringStream(const TString &s) : MyStream(s) { }
    //and more...
    //operator>> overloads...
    //defines for VS2010/2015 (C++11) included

    inline WCStringStream &operator<<(const std::wstring &s)
    {
        if (typeid(TString) == typeid(s))
            MyStream::operator<<(s.c_str());
        else
            *this << std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>, wchar_t>().to_bytes(s);
        return *this;
    }

    inline WCStringStream &operator<<(const std::string &s)
    {
        if (typeid(TString) == typeid(s))
            MyStream::operator<<(s.c_str());
        else
            *this << std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>, wchar_t>().from_bytes(s);
        return *this;
    }
};

//Example main
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    typedef std::wstring fstring;

    WCStringStream<std::wstring> ws;
    WCStringStream<std::string> ss;

    ws << fstring(L"123");
    int a = 0;
    ws >> a;
    std::cout << a << std::endl;

    ss << fstring(L"123");
    int b = 0;
    ss >> b;
    std::cout << b << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

*I'm compiling currently in VS2015 but I'd need it to run on VS2010 too.*

Comment: I could have sworn that VS2010/2015s stock `stringstream` did this for you already

Comment: I am not totally clear on what the actual problem is from your description.  My first thought is that you should look at Template Specialization [http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/template_specialization.html]

Comment: @Mgetz There's `std::stringstream` and `std::wstringstream`, I'd like to "combine" these with additional functions not being displayed here.

Comment: Is the `typeid(..) == typeid(..)` supposed to be a compile-time check? Because it currently isn't.... Wouldn't `std::is_same<TString, std::string>::value` be more appropriate, or template specialization?

Comment: Could you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/MCVE)? It is not entirely clear to me how any other `operator<<` interact with the `*this << ...` expression.

Comment: @Blacktempel did you review the tutorial on specialization?

Comment: @dyp It is not supposed to be a compile-time check, else this would not compile. In which way would you recommend template specialization ? The whole class ? This may be able to work, though I'd prefer to have it all in one. This error seems trivial, but I cannot seem to figure out what it may be.

Comment: Instead of template specialization, you could make the conversion interface generic, that is, `std::string convert(std::wstring const&); std::wstring convert(std::string const&);`, then define the two operators e.g. via a type function `template<class T> using other_string_type = typename std::conditional<std::is_same<T, std::string>::value, std::wstring, std::string>::type;` then `WCStringStream& operator<< (TString const&); WCStringStream& operator<< (other_string_type<TString> const&);`

Comment: @dyp That's indeed a good solution for C++11. Sadly template aliases are not supported in VS2010, but I will add a macro for the VS2015 compile, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was to explicitly call the base class operator, which takes the `const void *_Val` overload and prints the address.

```
MyStream::operator<<(s.c_str());
```

The solution to the problem:

```
if (typeid(TString) == typeid(s))
{
    MyStream &os = *this;
    os << s.c_str();
}
```

Of course calling `*this << s.c_str()` results in recursion, but the using the base class, it calls the global overloaded operator for the correct char-type `wchar_t` / `char`.

An also working solution is to use the member-function [`write`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/write/) instead of the operator.

Answer (score 2):

First off: I think the approach to overload formatting function in a base class is **ill-advised** and I *strongly* recommend to **not do it**! I do realize that any alternative will require a bit more work.

In fact, I think your primary problem is actually that you do **not** reach your overloaded functions anyway just showing how fragile the approach is (I *think* the string describe what overload ends up being called but I haven't verified that these are indeed accurate, partly because the code provided in the question is lacking necessary context):

```
WCStringStream<std::string> stream;
stream << "calls std::operator<< (std::ostream&, char const*)\n";
stream << L"calls std::ostream::operator<< (void const*)\n";
stream << std::string("calls std::operator<< (std::ostream&, T&&)\n";
std::string const s("calls your operator\n");
stream << s;
```

Since the overloaded output operators for strings and string literals can't be changed and they do the *wrong* think with respect to code conversions, I recommend using an entirely different approach although it still won't be without peril(*): convert the strings explicitly although using a more nicely packaged version of the code than the standard provides.

Assuming always using `char` as character type for all uses I would use a function `wcvt()` which is called for all strings and string-literals when inserting them into a stream. Since at the point the function is being called it wouldn't know the type of the stream it is going to be used with, it would return essentially a reference to the character sequence which is then converted appropriately for the character type used for the stream. That would be something along these lines:

```
template <typename cT>
class wconvert {
    cT const* begin_;
    cT const* end_;
public:
    wconvert(std::basic_string<cT> const& s)
        : begin_(s.data())
        , end_(s.data() + s.size()) {
    }
    wconvert(cT const* s)
    : begin_(s)
    , end_(s + std::char_traits<cT>::length(s)) {
    }
    cT const* begin() const { return this->begin_; }
    cT const* end() const { return this->end_; }
    std::streamsize size() const { return this->end_ - this->begin_; }
};

template <typename cT>
wconvert<cT> wcvt(cT const* s) {
    return wconvert<cT>(s);
}
template <typename cT>
wconvert<cT> wcvt(std::basic_string<cT> const& s) {
    return wconvert<cT>(s);
}

template <typename cT>
std::basic_ostream<cT>& operator<< (std::basic_ostream<cT>& out,
                                    wconvert<cT> const& cvt) {
    return out.write(cvt.begin(), cvt.size());
}

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, wconvert<wchar_t> const& cvt) {
    auto tmp = std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>, wchar_t>().to_bytes(cvt.begin(), cvt.end());
    return out.write(tmp.data(), tmp.size());
}

std::wostream& operator<< (std::wostream& out, wconvert<char> const& cvt) {
    auto tmp = std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>, wchar_t>().from_bytes(cvt.begin(), cvt.end());
    return out.write(tmp.data(), tmp.size());
}
```

Of course, using this approach requires the use of `wcvt(s)` whenever `s` may be a string which needs to be converted. It is easy to forget doing so and it seems the original objective was to *not* have to remember the use of such a conversion. However, I don't see any alternative which is less fragile with the system of existing streams. Entirely abandoning the use of streams and using an entirely separate system of formatted I/O *may* yield less fragile approach.

(*) The approach easiest to get right is to stick with just on character type in a program and *always* using this character type. I do believe it was actually an error to introduce a second character type, `wchar_t`, and it an even bigger error to further complicate the existing mess by having also introduced `char16_t` and `char32_t`. We'd be much better off there were just one character type, `char`, although it actually wouldn't represent character but bytes of an encoding.

Comment: First off, thank you for your answer. This is not any base class, it is a class without any further needs to inherit from it. I have updated the question to be more clear in all, I thought the `*this <<` operator being called was obvious that the functions are inside the class, but it seems like it wasn't. - Yes the easiest is to stick with one character in a program, though there are some external libraries and functions, which do not support Unicode (yet). Indeed the original objective is, not to check (outside of this class) if it's a `std::wstring` or `std::string`.